# Dynamic Asset Sub Folder Paths based on section and. if/else or turnery operators

Tags: assets, assets-field, subfolder

How can I create dynamic paths for asset uploads?
Basically I want my structure to be like so;

```
company-name-slug
  company
    logo-1.jpg
    image-2.jpg
  products
    product-image-1.jpg
  services
    service-image-1.jpeg
    service-image-2.jpeg
```

I have a field called gallery for the above assets.

Then I have sections for company, products and services.
Each section uses the gallery field. Products and Services uses a related content field for the company (called company).

I want to use the gallery field across all sections, but then set the dynamic paths per service/product and company inline with the above structure.

Here is what I have tried but it just errors out. I have tried various combinations and some work some don't, but I cannot get to desired structure.

```
{% section == 'Company' ? slug : company.one|kebab %}/{section|kebab}
```

How can I achieve this or is there a way I can inject some better twig logic into the subfolder field?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So this was a simple fix and not to use `{% %}` tags but instead to use `{{ }}` tags. Changing the above logic in the subdirectories filed like so seems to have resolved the issue.

```
{{ section == 'Company' ? slug : company.one|kebab }}/{section|kebab}
```